# Adding Android support libraries without resources to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

I'm having a hard time adding Android support libraries without resources to eclipse.
I've followed the steps one by one from [official guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) but i still have the little "red x"

this is the xml error that i have

> error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton'.

Comment: AppCompact is a library with resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i didn't notice a little note they had at the bottom of the page

> Note: If you are using the **android-support-v7-mediarouter** support library, you should note that it depends on the android-support-v7-appcompat library. In order for the v7 mediarouter library to compile, you must import both library projects into your development workspace. **Then follow the procedure above to add the v7 appcompat project as a library to the v7 mediarouter library project**.